# How to send Email Reminder after a specific time using phpmyadmin and asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

Hello everyone and best regards,

To clarify the question, I have a table of users in my database on phpMyAdmin. Each time the user logs in, a column that is called "UserActivity" type DATETIME is updated in the table to the current date that the user logged in. Now, if the user did not log in for 15 days (half a month), he would receive an Email informing him to be active on my web site.

How is this possible? Is it with using MySQL Scheduled Event? Or by using a web service?

I would be really appreciated if you help me with this.

Much Love,

Majid Abu Rmelah.

Comment: You cannot do it with phpMyAdmin, for a start that is not a database, its a tool written in PHP to make fiddling with MYSQL databases easier for the beginner

Comment: I would suggest as simple script that finds all the people from your database and then sends them an email. And you run this as a CRON Job

Comment: How to make a CRON Job in asp.net?

Comment: Ah sorry. If you are on Windows then that should have been Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Task Scheduler and making a windows form in visual studio.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are making an app, you can use Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/). Firebase makes it possible to send e-mails to the users for free.

Comment: What makes you think OP is developing an app?